# How to compile python2 v2.7.16 under Mingw-w64 (I have got compile errors)

Tags: python, compiler-errors, compilation, mingw-w64, msys2

I have tried to compile python2 v2.7.16 using the MINGW-packages git repo:

`git clone https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages.git`

`cd MINGW-packages/mingw-w64-python2`

`MINGW_INSTALLS='mingw32' makepkg-mingw -dLf --nocheck --skippgpcheck`

I always get the following errors:

````
../Python-2.7.16/Python/random.c:247:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fcntl'; did you mean 'rintl'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         attr = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
                ^~~~~
                rintl
../Python-2.7.16/Python/random.c:247:26: error: 'F_GETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
         attr = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
                          ^~~~~~~
../Python-2.7.16/Python/random.c:247:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../Python-2.7.16/Python/random.c:249:21: error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'S_IEXEC'?
             attr |= FD_CLOEXEC;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
                     S_IEXEC
../Python-2.7.16/Python/random.c:250:29: error: 'F_SETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
             (void)fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, attr);
                             ^~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:1376: Python/random.o] Error 1
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...```
````

Comment: Those names (`fcntl`, `F_GETFD`, `F_SETFD` and `FD_CLOEXEC`) are normally defined in `fcntl.h`. But it appears that MingW's `fcntl.h` doesn't define these?

Comment: Ah, MingW doesn't define these because Win32 doesn't offer this API at all. Did you follow the instructions from https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#GCC_-_MinGW-w64_.28x86.2C_x64.29 ?

Comment: I see from [this post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-January/123774.html), [this page](https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/mingw_python.html) and other context that Python source doesn't appear to support building on MingW, not without patching.

Comment: Python requires a *lot* of patches when you compile it in MSYS2.  You can see them all here:  https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-python2